# Did Mongolian president Ochirbat Punsalmaa make a funny remark about a snoring bodyguard to Queen Elizabeth II on a visit to the UK in 1996?

Tags: history

According to [this widely shared Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-cultural-faux-pas-among-diplomats/answer/AmgaIan-Ganbat), the following interesting story took place when the Mongolian president visited the UK in 1996:

> In 1996, Mongolia's first president, Ochirbat Punsalmaa, paid an official visit to the UK.
>
> As a part of his visit, he and the Queen watched a ballet concert. In
> the midst of the concert, someone started to snore. As the sound of
> snoring became more disturbing, so that everyone, including the queen
> and the president, tried to find who it was, it turned-out to be one
> of Ochirbat's bodyguards.
>
> Somewhat worried, the Queen asked Ochirbat if they should wake the
> poor bodyguard up. In response to that, Ochirbat said, "Oh, please
> don't. Look at your dancers, pointing to the ballerinas being on
> demi-pointe (tip-toeing), even they are trying hard not to wake him
> up."

I did some quick googling, and it seems that president Ochirbat Punsalmaa did indeed meet the queen in 1996.  However, I was able to find no reference at all (at least in English language sources) to this alleged ballet concert other than this Quora answer.

Comment: What does *first president* mean?